# How do I plumb LP gas lines for multiple things? Tiki torches, grill, smoker

Tags: deck, gas, propane

I am an experienced DYIer and am starting my research on building my deck. I would like to plumb it for eight tiki torches, a grill and a smoker. I have experience plumbing gas, I plumbed my last house for natural gas. I would like to know where to turn to answer my questions on "Will I have enough pressure to operate all at the same time" and "How many torches can I run in a single line."

Comment: The title and body of your post don't match. Are you asking **us** how to do it, or are you asking us **where** to post your real questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really asking a flow question.
How many CFM (cubic feet per minute) does a given size pipe supply.  The upper limit will be the meter capacity/ pipe size from the street.

Each device has a max flow rating.  Add them up and compare to the size piping you are planning to use.  Increase the pipe diameter as necessary (up to the size coming in to the meter.

Comment: Agreed,  RTFM.  The documentation will list the requirements for each fixture, install pipe accordingly.